# How can i smoothly scroll between NestedScrollView and ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following simple full code ..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  const Profile({ Key? key, }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  ProfileState createState() => ProfileState();
}


class ProfileState extends State<Profile>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (context,value){
            return[
              const SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 400,
              )
            ];
          },
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 200,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Center(child: Text(index.toString()));
            },
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

in the previous code, everything is ok and it shifted the scroll in a smooth way BUT when I provide `ScrollController` into my `ListView.builder` the scroll is no longer smooth anymore.

so Please How could I keep the first result (with no providing ScrollController) the same as (with providing ScrollController)? .

Comment: Just a tip: CustomScrollView with SliverAppBar and SliverListBuilder may fall helpful, you keep the expandable header feature plus a lazy loaded list, all with a single scroll controller.

Comment: are you sure from SliverListBuilder  ? it give me red line .. do you mean SliverFixedExtentList ?

Comment: my bad, I meant SliverList + SliverListBuiderDelegate. Take a look at https://medium.flutterdevs.com/customscrollview-slivers-in-flutter-72169ed264b7.

Comment: can you provide small example of it as answer to accept it . i think this is what i looking for .

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your requirements using `CustomScrollView`, the API is "harder" to use but it allows you implement more complex features (like nested scrollviews as you are doing) because we have direct access to the [Slivers API](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/slivers).

You can see that almost any Flutter scrollable widget is a derivation of either `CustomScrollView` or `ScrollView` which makes use of Slivers.

- [NestedScrollView is a subclass of CustomScrollView](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/nested_scroll_view.dart).
- [ListView and GridView widgets are subclasses of ScrollView](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart).

Although seems complicated a Sliver is just a portion of a scrollable area:

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  controller: _scrollController, 
  slivers: [
    const SliverAppBar(expandedHeight: 400),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (context, index) {
          return Center(child: Text('item $index.'));
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

So, instead of creating multiple scrollviews and trying to mix them together (which lead to buggy behaviors), just declare multiple scrollable areas and put them together inside a `CustomScrollView`, that's it.

See the working example at: https://dartpad.dev/?id=60cb0fa073975f3c80660815ae88af4e.